# A weird difference between .css and .animate using % positioning in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have this code which work as intended. Notice that the first animate has 0 duration.

```
$(".myClass").animate({'top': '-=100%'}, 0).animate({top: '+=100%'}, 500);
```

Basically, I want to place an element with class myClass that is positioned correctly if javascript is disabled. If javascript is enabled, I would first make the element start outside the container and bring it in to its original position. I tried using this code.

```
$(".myClass").css({'top': '-=100%'}).animate({top: '+=100%'}, 500);
```

I was expecting that these two would do the same, but the .css method is acting in a different way. It's as if when using percentage, -=100% with .css means -100% of the element's height while with .animate means -100% of the element's container's height.

Is this supposed to work this way or I have done something wrong. More code available on request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's supposed to work this way AFAIK. The CSS property doesn't use the += and -= operators because it's setting a hard value rather than approaching or calculating one (like animate).

Comment: That is correct. The jQuery team thought it would be nice to be able to animate relative to the current value (hence the += and -= operators). The css function doesn't support this because it is not valid css.

Answer (score 0):

We can only use +=,-= for relative animations in animate() while css() does not allows this .so this not works for you